# Duplicate data in a dynamic JavaFX TableView

Tags: javafx

I have a table which is loaded dynamically from a given database; the problem is that it duplicates data. Here is the method that generates the table:

```
@FXML
public void buildCentres() {
    Connection c;
    ResultSet result;
    ObservableList<ObservableList> centers = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    try {
        c = DBconnection.getconection_planning();
        result = c.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT centreno,centrename FROM plan_centres");

        for (int i = 0; i < result.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            final int j = i;
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(result.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
                }
            });

            HomeView.getColumns().addAll(col);
        }

        while (result.next()) {
            //Iterate Row
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for (int i = 1; i <= result.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                //Iterate Column
                row.add(result.getString(i));
            }

            centers.add(row);
        }

        HomeView.setItems(null);
        HomeView.setItems(centers);
        c.close();
        result.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Something to notify
    }
}
```

Here is the interface:

[image: Interface]

The columns and rows are duplicating and when I want to clear the table and load something else, it adds on the new content as a column in the existing columns.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: [mcve] please .. and stick to java naming conventions!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create columns on each query.

Either wrap first loop in `if (HomeView.getColumns().isEmpty())` or clear them before the first loop.

Rows generating code looks fine, so make sure you are not calling `buildCentres()` twice and that DB doesn't have duplicates.